# How to send keystrokes in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to send a keystrokes to the system (metro style apps). The keys like right arrow or left arrow.

In windows forms it's easy to do with `SendKeys()`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("S");
```

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: No. That would violate separation.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Not legally, anyway.